# Cannot connect AWS lambda function to SQL RDB using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I have a Stack in AWS CDK where I have added Lambda that should connect to RDS which is also instantiated in Stack, and it should create a table. When I hit this lambda returns 502 "message": "Internal server error". Maybe I need some policies to include?

The Lambda functions have IAM policies attached to them using the "PolicyStatement" class. The "s3ListPolicy" policy allows the Lambda functions to list all S3 buckets. The "rdsReadPolicy" policy allows the "readLambda" and "initCreateTab" functions to connect to the RDS instance.

But I think it is not enough it should be something else.

Stack

```
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as rds from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';

import { Function as LambdaFunction, Runtime } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { join } from 'path';
import { LambdaIntegration, RestApi } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import { PolicyStatement } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';


export class ReserveStack extends cdk.Stack {
  private api : RestApi = new RestApi(this, 'SpaceApi')

  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'cdk-vpc-rds', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      natGateways: 0,
      maxAzs: 3,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: 'public-subnet-1',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          cidrMask: 24,
        },
        {
          name: 'isolated-subnet-1',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
          cidrMask: 28,
        },
      ],
    });

    // create a security group for the EC2 instance
    const ec2InstanceSG = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'ec2-instance-sg', {
      vpc,
    });

    ec2InstanceSG.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
      ec2.Port.tcp(22),
      'allow SSH connections from anywhere',
    );


    // create RDS instance
    const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'db-instance', {
      vpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
      },
      engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql({
        version: rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_8_0_26
      }),
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
        ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3,
        ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO,
      ),
      credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('admin'),
      multiAz: false,
      allocatedStorage: 110,
      maxAllocatedStorage: 127,
      allowMajorVersionUpgrade: false,
      autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,
      backupRetention: cdk.Duration.days(0),
      deleteAutomatedBackups: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      deletionProtection: false,
      databaseName: 'reservationsDb',
      publiclyAccessible: false,
    });


    const initCreateTab = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ininCreateTab', {
      vpc,
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      entry: (join(__dirname, '..', 'services', 'crud-lambda', 'initCreateTab.ts')),
      handler: 'handler',
    })


    // Lambda integrations
    const helloLambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(helloLambdaNodeJs);
    const helloLambdaResource = this.api.root.addResource('hello');
    helloLambdaResource.addMethod('GET', helloLambdaIntegration);

    const readLambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(readLambda);
    const readLambdaResource = this.api.root.addResource('readLambda');
    readLambdaResource.addMethod('GET', readLambdaIntegration);

    const initCreateTabIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(initCreateTab);
    const initCreateTabResource = this.api.root.addResource('createTable');
    initCreateTabResource.addMethod('GET', initCreateTabIntegration);

    const s3ListPolicy = new PolicyStatement();
    s3ListPolicy.addActions('s3:ListAllMyBuckets');
    s3ListPolicy.addResources('*');
    helloLambdaNodeJs.addToRolePolicy(s3ListPolicy);

    readLambda.addToRolePolicy(s3ListPolicy);

    const rdsReadPolicy = new PolicyStatement();
    rdsReadPolicy.addActions('rds-db:connect');
    rdsReadPolicy.addResources(dbInstance.secret!.secretArn);

    readLambda.addToRolePolicy(rdsReadPolicy);
    initCreateTab.addToRolePolicy(rdsReadPolicy);


    // dbInstance.connections.allowFrom(ec2Instance, ec2.Port.tcp(5432));

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'dbEndpoint', {
      value: dbInstance.instanceEndpoint.hostname,
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'secretName', {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain
      value: dbInstance.secret?.secretName!,
    });
  }
}
```

And Lambda:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

const rdsDataService = new AWS.RDSDataService();



export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {
  const createTableQuery = `
    CREATE TABLE Reservations (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        firstName VARCHAR(255),
        lastName VARCHAR(255),
        email VARCHAR(255),
        phone VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
  `;

  const params = {
    resourceArn: 'arn:aws:rds:ca-central-1:201682123230:db:reservestack-dbinstance310a317f-gjixavyg2vyd',
    secretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:201682123230:secret:ReserveStackdbinstanceSecre-ODm947ED1NFz-XPwT45',
    sql: createTableQuery,
    database: 'reservationsDb'
  };

  try {
    const result = await rdsDataService.executeStatement(params).promise();
    console.log(result);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Table created successfully'
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'Error creating table'
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the RDS has to be in a VPC.  So to talk to it the lambda has to be inside the same VPC.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes it is in the same VPC.

const initCreateTab = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ininCreateTab', {
      vpc,
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      entry: (join(__dirname, '..', 'services', 'crud-lambda', 'initCreateTab.ts')),
      handler: 'handler',
    })

Comment: Check the lambda logs and add them to the question.

Comment: Your lambdas are in an Isolated subnet - they cannot make any calls to the internet or to AWS APIs. You'll need to create VPC endpoints for each service the lambdas need to call.